# Why the WebView is always on top and can't handle focus etc.?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Suppose you have in your Metro application the WebView component taking all the "page" height (except the "title bar" of course). At the left side from the WebView you have some other elements. You also have some buttons in appBar with ListView menus attached to the button press events. Now try to see your ListViews and also try to move focus between the page elements with TAB key ;)
I already have some workarounds.
I just wanted to ask if somebody knows WHY Microsoft did it so?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx#AN2) ?

Comment: @Xyroid: thanks. So this is a bug or the "Airspace" issue was made intentionally? And what about "no focus" issue?

Comment: It might be bug as WinRT is in its initial phase.

Comment: Its not a bug.  It's a limitation of the way Microsoft implemented the WebView.

Comment: I tried using WebView in one of my apps, found it difficult to get a useful experience for the page. in my case, content was simple enough that I transformed to xaml and used RichTextBlock control instead.

Answer (score 0):

The WebView has it's own HWND (Window), while your Metro app renders in a second HWND.  There is a long history in Windows development regarding windows and overlaps.  Usually when a window is in front of another window, the OS only draws the top window pixels.

That's what's happening here.   The WebView windows is drawing over top of your other UI elements.

Comment: Surprise - unlike ListView the PopupMenu overlaps the WebView! So I'm not sure the problem is in old good handles, I believe the problem really is "a long story of Windows development" :)

Comment: I believe the Popup has it's own HWND too.  I know it does in WPF.  If it does then it can float over the other HWND.